# Calculating number of days worked excluding holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a situtation where i have to find out th enumber of days a person present/worked in a given range of dates (FROM-TO)

Parent Table's Data is Stored in #EMP with days bit on where his working days,I have #EMPCHILD in which his attendance marked datewise,

I have to calculate that a employee has worked how many days excluding his off days , I am not gettting how may i query that it given me the number of counts between dates for the employee worked.
Kindly help any body, below I am pasting the SQL Script for Tables with Data

```
CREATE TABLE #EMP
(
    eid INT default 0,
    sun bit default 1,
    mon bit default 1,
    tue bit default 1,
    wed bit default 1,
    thu bit default 1,
    fri bit default 1,
    sat bit default 1
)
CREATE TABLE #EMPCHILD
(
    eid INT default 0,
    [date] DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #EMP VALUES(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #EMP VALUES(2,0,0,1,0,1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #EMP VALUES(3,0,1,0,0,1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #EMP VALUES(4,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)


INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-02')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-03')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-04')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-05')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-06')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-07')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-08')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-09')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-10')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-02')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-03')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(2,'2014-03-04')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-05')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(4,'2014-03-06')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(2,'2014-03-07')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(4,'2014-03-08')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-09')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-10')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(2,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(4,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(2,'2014-03-02')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(1,'2014-03-01')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(2,'2014-03-03')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(4,'2014-03-04')
INSERT INTO #EMPCHILD VALUES(3,'2014-03-01')

SELECT * from #EMP
SELECT * from #EMPCHILD




DROP TABLE #EMP
DROP TABLE #EMPCHILD
```

Now I want that it will calculate days worked by an Employee(overtime as well) as Days count between
**2014-01-01  TO  2014-01-08**

By Applying below query :

```
SELECT #EMP.eid,COUNT(*) FROM #EMP
LEFT JOIN #EMPCHILD ON #EMPCHILD.eid = #EMP.eid
WHERE #EMPCHILD.[Date] between '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-08'

GROUP BY #EMP.eid
```

[image: Query Result]
[image: Tentive Plan]

Comment: Is it your existing data model or you are flexible in changing table design?

Comment: No, My curent scenario is strictly as I have sescribed

Comment: this is the weirdst way to store this kind of information I ever seen in my whole life

Comment: sometimes, it's way better to just write some code outside the DB to calculate information that is business logic instead of trying to solve this kind of problem with barebones SQL

Comment: What do you mean by "Employee's days off" will not always be Saturday and Sunday ??? or every employee has it own particular days off ???

Comment: Give some hints on how these 2 tables should be joined into something that makes sense.

Comment: @M.Ali : Its random, An Employee can work for 7 days even, An Employee can be at OffDays other then Regular (SAT,SUN)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3255c/1 THe fiddle

Comment: @Mihai: I have added the joined queries and also result set

Comment: Note that you [shouldn't be using BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  What do you do about historical data - what happens if next week I'm scheduled different days?  If there's no way to tell when scheduling has changed, you're screwed.  Your setup also seems to assume that a full shift is worked.  What happens if I go home early?  Or if I mistakenly clock-in for an hour on my day off?  Do shifts cross over midnight (in multiple calendar days)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Buddy the schedule is set only once, if changed,in next calculation IsDayWorked will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3255c/20

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-03-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2014-03-09'

DECLARE @EId INT = 1

SELECT EC.*,

  CASE DATEPART(dw, [date])
    WHEN 1 THEN sun
    WHEN 2 THEN mon
    WHEN 3 THEN tue
    WHEN 4 THEN wed
    WHEN 5 THEN thu
    WHEN 6 THEN fri
    WHEN 7 THEN sat
  END AS IsWorkingDay

FROM EMPCHILD EC
INNER JOIN EMP E
 ON E.eid = EC.eid
WHERE [date] >= @StartDate
AND [date] < @EndDate
AND EC.eid = @EId
```

AFTER EDIT:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3255c/22

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-03-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2014-03-09'

SELECT Eid, COUNT(1)
FROM (

SELECT EC.*,

  CASE DATEPART(dw, [date])
    WHEN 1 THEN sun
    WHEN 2 THEN mon
    WHEN 3 THEN tue
    WHEN 4 THEN wed
    WHEN 5 THEN thu
    WHEN 6 THEN fri
    WHEN 7 THEN sat
  END AS IsWorkingDay

FROM EMPCHILD EC
INNER JOIN EMP E
 ON E.eid = EC.eid
WHERE [date] >= @StartDate
AND [date] < @EndDate
) tbl
WHERE IsWorkingDay = 1
GROUP BY Eid
```

Comment: Bro I want to Count **ISWorkingDay** Group By eid, Please modify query

Comment: Buddy the thing is , I have to calculate only the Days of Employee , EMPCHILD is only used for date selection , I want to get the count of an Employee , despite the days he attended. I have sun~sat days bits. I just want that an employee having this schedule how many days due to work

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.date,l.eid, dayWeek, isWork
from (
select eid,sun as [1], mon as [2], tue as [3], wed as [4], thu as [5] , fri as [6], sat as [7]  from #emp)p
unpivot 
(iswork for dayWeek in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]))l
inner join #EMPCHILD e on e.eid=l.eid and datepart(dw,e.date)=l.dayWeek
order by eid,date
```

This query return you a table of working and not working days for each worker

Comment: Your query is Fine , but I need the ctotal counts of the working days like group by clause with EMP.eid, can you help me?